# SwiftUI View Hierarchy Warning in One Case and Not Another

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I originally crafted a SwiftUI list/detail app that included a TabView with one tab as the view to add new records. That works pretty much as expected. I wanted to change that add functionality from a tab to be called from a navigation bar button. I'm using the exact same view in both cases. When the view is called from the nav bar button, I get the tableView hierarchy error:

[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and
other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its
superviews has not been added to a window)....+ lots more chatter

The TabView call:

```
AddNewPatient().tabItem ({
    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
    Text("Add")
})
.tag(2)
```

And the navigation button call:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: AddNewPatient()) {
    Text("Add Patient")
})
```

I'm confused as to why the view is out of hierarchy when called from the nav bar button. So far, I have not experience an app crash, but clearly the app is unhappy. The data is indeed saved and is shown in the list. (Core Data store)

I set a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy but all I
could glean was the same data - outside the view hierarchy.

Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) iOS 13.1.2

Any guidance would be appreciated.

The AddNewPatient view:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AddNewPatient: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        
    @State private var updatedTitle: String = "No Title"
    @State private var updatedFirstName: String = "No First Name"
    //more properties
    
    @State var photos: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()
    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    
    var bImage: Image = Image("InventoryThinBlueWithCamera")

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
            VStack {
                if photos.count > 0 {
                    Image(uiImage: photos[photos.count - 1])
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 320, height: 320)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                } else {
                    bImage
                }

                VStack {
                Button("Take Photo") {
                    self.showImagePicker = true
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                //.disabled(!showAlert)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
                    PhotoCaptureView(photos: self.$photos)
                }

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Patient Title:")
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .font(.headline)
                    TextField("Enter a Title", text: $updatedTitle)
                        .onAppear {
                            self.updatedTitle = ""
                    }
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
                .padding(10)
                
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("First Name:")
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .font(.headline)
                    TextField("Enter First Name", text: $updatedFirstName)
                        .onAppear {
                            self.updatedFirstName = ""
                    }
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
                .padding(10)
                
                //bunch more fields
                

                
                Spacer()
            }
        }//ScrollView
        .navigationBarTitle("Add New Patient", displayMode: .inline)
        .padding(.top, 50)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:  Button(action: ({
                    
            let nmo = Patient(context: self.managedObjectContext)
            var chosenImageData : Data?

            if self.photos.count > 0 {
                let theImage = self.photos[self.photos.count - 1]
                
                let rir = CRSReduceImageResolution()
                let temp = rir.resizeMyImageData(theImage, startSize: CGSize.zero, endSize: CGSize(width: 320, height: 240))
                chosenImageData = temp
                //chosenImageData = myImageData
                nmo.image = chosenImageData
            }

            nmo.myID = UUID()
            nmo.title = self.updatedTitle
            nmo.firstName = self.updatedFirstName
            nmo.lastName = self.updatedLastName
            nmo.createdAt = Date()
            
            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
                    
            self.photos = []
                    self.updatedTitle = ""
                    self.updatedFirstName = ""
                    //bunch more fields
                })) {
                    Text("Save")
                })
        }//nav
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the body for the AddNewPatient view?

Comment: The AddNewPatient view code is added above.

Comment: I can't see where the table view would be created in the view code. You have no List.

Comment: This is not a tableview. This is the equivalent of the detail view from UIKit master/detail. I am calling this view from a nav bar button on the list view.

Comment: In that case I don't understand the error `Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the trailing button call to toggle a property to show the add patient sheet, then called a function to add the patient. This works perfectly.

```
 .navigationBarTitle("Person")
 .sheet(isPresented: $showAddPatient) {
      AddNewPatient(photoStore: self.photoStore)
  }

  .navigationBarItems(
       leading: EditButton(),
       trailing: Button(
           action: {
               withAnimation { self.showAddPatient.toggle() }
           }
        ) {
          Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
```